# Get values of plots from a chart in webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the data-values from the first plot plot in the page https://www.bing.com/covid.

When I check the corresponding DOM element div `infoTile graph multiLineGraph`, I see data for only one date is available.

Is there any way to fetch all the data points?

I am using Python3 for srcapping the data.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about https://github.com/microsoft/Bing-COVID-19-Data ?

Comment: While this is excellent, but it would still be helpful to have a way to scrape data directly from site given that repo updates data with 24 hours delay